# Proper way to setup Oauth 2.0 server and grant types for handling system calls, user calls, and third-party calls?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm developing a software application which will require OAuth 2.0.  I'd like some suggestions and insight on the best way to go about properly generating and assigning the correct tokens (what method of assignment or grant type) for each entity listed below.  I am not talking about specifics related to the software I’ll be using to implement the solution—I already know that I’m going to be using the Slim Framework in conjunction with Chadicus\Slim\OAuth2 which incorporates http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/.

Rather, the ideal answer to my question will be a high level listing of what methods of token generation (grant type) is ideal for supporting each of the entities in the application which will be doing certain things.  Your answer should include the specific grant type that is most proper for each entity and whether I'm thinking correctly in terms of how to handle the entity (especially in dealing with the System entity).

**Entities**

I have the following entities which will be making API calls within the system:

1. **Internal System** - A single entity where calls made will manipulate system settings which are not on behalf of any user (e.g. update a system-wide setting such as global color, create a new user, generate a report listing logins for a certain day)
2. **Logged In Users** - For users who are registered and logged in and want to do certain things within the actual web application (e.g. create a new resource, update contact info, modify an existing resource)
3. **Third-Party Apps** - After a user has approved the app, the app will take actions on behalf of users to do certain things (e.g. the same things a regular user might do when logged in)

**Best Guesses**

There are several grant types listed on http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/grant-types/ which include the following which I think are the most relevant:

1. *Authorization Code (3-legged)*
2. *Resource Owner Password Credentials (User Credentials)*
3. *Client Credentials*

I am unsure which is the appropriate grant type for each of the three entities I listed earlier (which are system, users, and third-pary apps). I have a *guess* as to what the appropriate process should be when generating tokens, but it is only a guess and I’d like correction and/or clarification.  Here are my best guesses:

1. **Internal System** - I should create the first user in my entire application which will be a special user and call him “System”.  He’s the only special user in the entire users table.  The “System” user would then use his username/password and OAuth 2.0 to generate an access token via *Client Credentials* grant type with the permissions “system” associated with it.  This access token is stored in the database and could then be used going forward when making internal system-specific API calls. Or should I use *Resource Owner Password Credentials* grant type? Or should I not even create a special user called "System" at all?
2. **Logged In Users** - When a user first gets an account I use the user’s username/password and my OAuth 2.0 to generate an access token via *Resource Owner Password Credentials* grant type that is to be used solely by the user when using the application.  The permissions associated with the user would be “users-all” and the access token is stored secretly in the database and used going forward for a user’s own actions when logged into the system.  Or do I use *Client Credentials*?
3. **Third-Party Apps** - I think this is pretty clear to me.  I would use *Authorization Code (3-legged)* grant type to issue an access token for the app that will make calls on behalf of the user.

My real issue is how to treat the System and Users entities in my application.  Which grant type should I use?  Client Credentials and Resource Owner Password Credentials both seem correct and I'm confused.  What is the difference between a Resource Owner Password Credentials and a Client Credentials grant type?  What is an example of when Client Credentials would be used instead of Resource Owner Password Credentials?  Further, are the username/password referenced in those grant types the actual username/password of my users or are they generated random text strings that my OAuth 2.0 implementation will auto-generate for me?

**For Example**

Take for instance leading software applications today such as Facebook and Twitter which accomplish the same things I’m trying to do.  In those systems there is some system entity which handles system-related things presumably by making internal API calls.  There are also actual logged in users who make posts or tweet without the use of a third-party app since they’re logged into the very system they’re using.  Finally, there are third-party apps which a user allows to make posts and tweets on its behalf.  What do those applications do?

Finally, if I’m structuring this or thinking about it all wrong then please guide me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Per my coworker Phil,

Authorization code whenever possible, possibly resource owner password credentials when using internal CLI tools or code that lives on the same machine and doesn't communicate publicly

OFC this is if you want to be super duper secure

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/290511/auth-options-for-distributed-systems

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  There will be no CLI component to our API so I'm not concerned with that.  Also, I think an Authorization Code grant type would be overkill for my System and Users entities—it might not even be appropriate grant type given the circumstances.  In order to use an Authorization Code grant type for the System and Users entities I'd have to create a separate third-party app (which would be ours) for each entity and then have the System user and Users user jump through a 3-legged process simply to get a token for an already trusted system.

Comment: After reading through https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/#authorization I'm beginning to think that I should just rely on a Password grant type for both my System entity and Users entities.  Even though I hash stored passwords the user nevertheless needs to login at some point where their passwords are in cleartext and at that time I could regenerate/refresh an access token using the Password grant type.  I'm still left wondering, however, if there's a best practices article or guidelines that explicitly addresses exactly what I want and need to do.  Thanks again for your answer.